# Index was outside the bounds of the array systems.diagnostic.process

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

Unhandled Exception:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

---

> At HPLog.MultiLevelPointer.ProcessMem.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Seif\
>   Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HPLog\HPLog\Program.cs:line 61
>   Press any key to continue . . .

```
Line61   System.Diagnostics.Process[] Client =  
                System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Client");
         ProcessMemoryReader preader = new ProcessMemoryReader();

         preader.ReadProcess = Client[0];
         preader.OpenProcess();
```

Comment: Besides, that there's no question: `Client` is an empty array - that's why you get the exception.

Answer (score 4):

Hows this: an answer when you didn't even ask a question!

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] Client =  
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Client");
 ProcessMemoryReader preader = new ProcessMemoryReader();

 if (Client != null && Client.Length > 0) {
     preader.ReadProcess = Client[0];
     preader.OpenProcess();
 }
 else {
     // Error handling...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this instead:

```
try
{
   System.Diagnostics.Process Client = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Client")[0];
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process Client = null;
}
```

Then before you use Client, make sure it is not null

Also, are you sure that 'Client' is the actual process name?

Answer (score 0):

Before using the array, you should test if it is `null` or contains any items. Since you always have a chance that a process with that name doesn't exist.